# Convert NSMutableData to NSString in Swift

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, swift

Currently, I am playing around with Swift.

I wanted to do a small downloader app with `NSURLConnection`. So far everything works fine, but I have 2 questions.

1. Why am I not able to convert my response data to `NSString`?
2. How can I convert my websever `NSURLResponse` to `NSHTTPURLResponse`?

So far my code looks like this:

```
import Foundation

class Downloader: NSObject, NSURLConnectionDelegate {

    let urlString: String
    var responseData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
    var responseMessage: NSURLResponse = NSURLResponse()

    init(urlString: String) {
        self.urlString = urlString.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);
    }

    func startDownloaderWithUrl() {
        let url: NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString(self.urlString);
        let r: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url);
        let connection:NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(
            request: r,
            delegate: self,
            startImmediately: true);
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didFailWithError error: NSError!) {
        NSLog("Connection failed.\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection, didRecieveResponse response: NSURLResponse)  {
        NSLog("Recieved response")
        self.responseMessage = response;
    }

    func connection(didReceiveResponse: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
        self.responseData = NSMutableData()
    }

    func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!) {
        self.responseData.appendData(data)
    }

    func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
        let responseString: NSString = NSString(data: self.responseData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding);

        NSLog("%@", "Finished Loading");
        //NSLog("%@", self.responseData);
        NSLog("%@", responseString);
    }
 }
```

My `responseString` is always `nil` although my `responseData` has a significant amount of bytes. Second how can I convert my response message to `NSHTTPURLResponse`?

Comment: I think your implementations are correct, check Encoding rather, try `NSASCIIStringEncoding`

Comment: Ok it was the wrong encoding that I used. NSASCIIStringEncoding works as expected. But I am sure that NSUTF8String encoding worked for me in previous pure Objective-C projects. Maybe you know how to convert NSURLRepsonse to NSHTTPURLResponse? I think it has to look like this `var urlRsponse = self.responseMessage as NSHTTPURLResponse` ?

Answer (score 3):

try tis

```
func connection(didReceiveResponse: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!) {
    self.data = NSMutableData()
}

func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!) {
    self.data.appendData(data)
}

func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!) {
    var dta = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println("the string is: \(dta)")

    }
```

Comment: Thank you but it was the wrong encoding I used. I have to wait one more day to accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Convert NSMutableData To String

```
var YourSting = NSString(data responseData: NSData!, encoding encoding: UInt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the encoding to ASCII worked for me.